# What's wrong with my code to dynamically get constants with dlsym in jailbroken iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, dlopen, tweak

I need to use `kIOSurfaceWidth` in my code to capture the screen shot, but for Apple has removed the `PrivateFrameworks` from iOS 9.3, so I have to load the `IOSurface.frameworks` dynamically at runtime. I use the code as below, but return not null it after `dlsym`, but when I try to `NSLog` the value of `kIOSurfaceWidth`, it crashes. Could anyone give me some help?

```
static CFStringRef _kIOSurfaceWidth;

static void load()
{
    void* handle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface", RTLD_LAZY);

    _kIOSurfaceWidth = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "kIOSurfaceWidth");
    if (!_kIOSurfaceWidth) LOG_GENERAL(@">>>>>>>> _kIOSurfaceWidth is NULL");
    else NSLOG(@"_kIOSurfaceWidth is %@", (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(_kIOSurfaceWidth));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dlsym()` gives you the address of the symbol, not its value. Change your code like so:

```
static CFStringRef *_kIOSurfaceWidth;

static void load()
{
    void* handle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface", RTLD_LAZY);

    _kIOSurfaceWidth = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "kIOSurfaceWidth");
    if (!_kIOSurfaceWidth) LOG_GENERAL(@">>>>>>>> _kIOSurfaceWidth is NULL");
    else NSLog(@"*_kIOSurfaceWidth is %@", *_kIOSurfaceWidth);
}
```

You also had other problems. Your log line was using `kIOSurfaceWidth` without a leading underscore (`_`), so it wasn't referring to your variable.

You were calling `CFBridgingRelease()` which is not appropriate unless you have an ownership reference. It's only appropriate in a case where you would be entitled to use `CFRelease()`, which is why it's named similarly. There should be no need to do a cast, bridging or otherwise, just to pass the string reference as a parameter to `NSLog()`.